# Ruby Encoding Issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, character-encoding

I am trying to get ruby to output

```
"m\\u00edstica"
```

on a text that has a lot of that kind of silly error. I realized that by removing the double backslash into a single backslash managed to make Ruby output "mística", however I am seem to be unable to use gsub for that purpose.

I tried using:

```
"m\\u00edstica".gsub('\\\\u') { '\\u' }
```

since I need to escape the backslash but it returns the very same string. Is there any way to decode this in a simple manner?

Comment: You are trying to do what exactly?

Comment: Get Ruby to output the correct accent and not \u00ed . I have over 3000 values with these kind of issues, so I need to find way to fix them programatically.

Comment: What version of Rails and Ruby are you using, and is this in a model or controller? Or is this data from your db?

Comment: It's data that is coming from a json that is crumpled up. Ruby version 2.2.2. It's not a model nor a controller, just a script.

Comment: What's the source of this json? Is it coming from an external API?

Answer (score 0):

A temporary work around was:
    "m\u00edstica".gsub(/\u[\da-f]{4}/i) { |m| [m[-4..-1].to_i(16)].pack('U') }